# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token using anchor tag in for each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my code

```js
function forgotpassword() {
  $('a').each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(element).attr("href") == "forgotpassword") {
      $(element).html("It Worked!"); // Change this to .html()
    } else {
      alert('not available');
    }
  });​
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

so its generated error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

and my code don't work

i have to compare `anchor href value` to another value

i have also search similar question in `stackoverflow` but it different type of code

Comment: If you edit your post and enter the snippet edit mode, then you have a `​​*`dot  at `});​` `});​*`

Comment: Note that I rolled back your edit as it introduced irrelevant code and also removed the invalid character, which was the entire point of the question

Comment: I can see it's the `\u200b` char `zero-width-space` that you most likely got from copy pasting

Answer (score 3):

If you check the error in the console, you can click the line number which causes the error and see the code:

[image]

You can see from the red dot that you have an illegal character; that is the source of your problem. Just delete that character and the code works without error:

```js
function forgotpassword() {
  $('a').each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(element).attr("href") == "forgotpassword") {
      $(element).html("It Worked!"); // Change this to .html()
    } else {
      alert('not available');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but how to remove run time

Comment: @Bhargav I don't understand what you mean? This issue is caused by a syntax error, it's not a runtime problem. You need to amend your code to fix it

Comment: It's because it's a non-printable character. You still need to delete it

Comment: but how without display * how i remove

Comment: @Bhargav, _how i remove_ delete that line and re-type it (don't copy paste it)